# What is causing racing condition in the buffered class

Tags: java, synchronization, synchronized, thread-synchronization

I'm trying to create a generic class to make some synchronized buffered writing operation.

I'm trying to minimize lock time, so i used a non final lock object that im my mind would be enough to keep the class synchronized and avoid racing condition... but while testing it i'm still getting racing condition and the final result is that some entities are flushed multiple times

can anyone try to explain me what is causing racing condition, what scenario is the cause of sync problem?

PLEASE DO NOT TELL ME TO MAKE THE METHOD flushCache SYNCHRONIZED... I KNOW HOW TO SOLVE THIS PROBLEM, im just trying to understand why it is happening

```
public abstract class SynchronizedBufferedSaver<E> {


   private final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;

   private Set<E> savingBuffer;

   public SynchronizedBufferedSaver(final int max_buffer_size) {
      MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = max_buffer_size;
      savingBuffer = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet((int) (max_buffer_size * 1.5));
   }


   public void save(@NonNull final E entity) {
      copyToCache(entity);
      flushCache(false);
   }

   abstract protected void persist(@NonNull final Set<E> cache);

   public void flushCache(final boolean force) {
      synchronized (savingBuffer) {
         if (!savingBuffer.isEmpty() && (force || savingBuffer.size() >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) {
            final Set<E> tmp = savingBuffer;
            savingBuffer = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet((int) (MAX_BUFFER_SIZE * 1.5));
            persist(tmp);
         }
      }
   }

   private void copyToCache(@NonNull final E entity) {
      savingBuffer.add(entity);
   }


}
```

Comment: Suppose thread A acquires the lock and thread B waits on it. By the time thread B acquires it, it could be a dead reference, and now it's flushing a newly created buffer that's already held by thread C.

Comment: @shmosel could you elaborate more?

Comment: You're acquiring a lock on the current instance of `savingBuffer`. Only one thread can acquire the lock on that instance, but multiple threads can still enter the code block at the same time as long as they're locking different instances. If the reference is replaced while you're waiting on the lock, you could be testing a different instance than you locked on. One way to avoid that is by capturing the field in a local variable and checking the same variable. Worst case it'll have been flushed already and you can move on.

Comment: A bigger problem is that `copyToCache()` is unsynchronized. There's no guarantee that the buffer you're writing to wasn't already flushed and discarded. And it won't help to synchronize on the buffer because it might be dead by the time you acquire it.

Comment: @shmosel reading your comments, I would like to ask: if thats the case, wouldnt OP be missing data? why would there be data that is flushed twice/multiple times?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X My first comment describes how it could duplicate flushes.

Comment: Is it that, while one thread has already changed/discarded the buffer, the other thread has not seen this change yet (volatile?) and when flushing again, it flushes the old buffer?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X The opposite. The old thread can end up flushing the new buffer at the same time as a newer thread.

Comment: Come to think of it, the local variable isn't a good idea for flushing either. If two threads capture two buffers, they'll both be able to lock and replace the field at the same time, which could result in one of them overwriting a live buffer.

Comment: @experimentunit1998X I think your scenario can't happen because the synchronized block itself creates a memory barrier similar to volatile. Ironically that only applies when it sees and synchronizes on the same old instance.

Answer (score 1):

Besides replacing `savingBuffer` (as said in the comments), you're mixing two different locking mechanisms here. `flushCache` uses the entire set as lock, but the call to `savingBuffer.add` inside `copyToCache` locks only a portion of the backing `ConcurrentHashMap`. That's because `ConcurrentHashMap` does not synchronize on the map itself. From [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is *not* any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access.

Your own solution of using a `HashSet` with synchronization solves the issue because now the same locking mechanism is used - `synchronized (savingBuffer)`. You can make life a bit easier by wrapping it in `Collections.synchronizedSet` because then all simple calls like `add` and `clear` will automatically use an intrinsic lock on `savingBuffer`. The `synchronized (savingBuffer)` inside `copyToCache` could be removed because it would already be part of the set.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up just giving up to try to reduce the synchronization blocks, it was too much effort for a small task.

I tried `volatile` and `atomicreference` without success

the following code will solve the problem with the extra synchronization block... although if anyone has an article or description of how that could be achieved with 1 synchronization block please send me i would love to learn

package br.com.fisgar.utils;

```
public abstract class SynchronizedBufferedSaver<E> {


   private final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE;

   private final Set<E> savingBuffer;

   public SynchronizedBufferedSaver(final int max_buffer_size) {
      MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = max_buffer_size;
      savingBuffer = new HashSet<>((int) (max_buffer_size * 1.5));
   }


   public void save(@NonNull final E entity) {
      copyToCache(entity);
      flushCache(false);
   }

   abstract protected void persist(@NonNull final Set<E> cache);

   public void flushCache(final boolean force) {
      final Set<E> tmp = new HashSet<>();
      synchronized (savingBuffer) {
         if (!savingBuffer.isEmpty() && (force || savingBuffer.size() >= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)) {
            tmp.addAll(savingBuffer);
            savingBuffer.clear();
         }
      }
      if (!tmp.isEmpty()) {
         persist(tmp);
      }
   }

   private void copyToCache(@NonNull final E entity) {
      synchronized (savingBuffer) {
         savingBuffer.add(entity);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to synchronize the method if you're already synchronizing on the final field.

Comment: I would suggest merging `copyToCache` and `flushCache` so you don't have acquire and release the same lock twice. But then the obvious question is, why even buffer?

Comment: persist is an io operation so the whole point of this class is to let other threads being able to work while a possible long running io is undergoing... this explains why the buffer also.

Comment: Never mind, I overlooked the buffer size check. Still, there's no reason not to merge  copy and flush. Your can still persist outside (though I would initialize `tmp` to null rather create a new set for each call).

Comment: @shmosel if i make `save` just a long method with the lines of `copy` and `flush` yet i will need another method to force flush as it a mechanism to ensure everything has been persisted